# Issue with the logic of the factorial function in the code, the function is not correctly calculating the factorial of the input integer n. Elixir

Tags: for-loop, elixir

The problem I'm having is that the loop doesn't seem to run and print the original "result" value.

```elixir
defmodule M do
  def factorial_(n) do
    result = 1

    for i <- 1..n do
      result = result * i
    end

    result
  end
end

IO.inspect(M.factorial_(5))
```

The output should be 120 but I keep getting 1. Assuming that the for loop it doesn't run at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop does run but remember Elixir is a functional language with immutable data structures.

I suggest reading this: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html

I know you have not asked about recursion but it is an essential technique, and perfectly suited for what you are doing.

Every time the `result = result * i` line is run, you are actually creating a new data structure in memory.

When I was starting with elixir, something that helped me a lot was to look at this code:

```elixir
x = for i <- 1..10 do
  i
end
```

In this code, the value of `x` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.

This code does the exact same thing:

```elixir
x = for i <- 1..10 do
  y = i
end
```

Moreover, the compiler (when you run `mix compile`) should warn you that "variable `y` is unused".

In your code, the compiler probably warns you that `result` is unused?

TL;DR - elixir data structures are immutable and if you want to use the result of a `for` loop then you need to assign it to a variable, e.g. `result = for _ <- 1..n do`. Anyway, use recursion for this problem.

Here is how I would do it:

```elixir
defmodule M do
  @doc """
  Gets the factorial of a non-negative number.

  Here's how factorials work:
  factorial(5) = 5! = 5 * 4! = 5 * 4 * 3! = ... = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
  """
  def factorial(n) when n < 0 do
    raise("Factorials don't work with negative numbers")
  end

  def factorial(0), do: 1
  def factorial(1), do: 1

  def factorial(n) when is_integer(n) do
    n * factorial(n - 1)
  end
end
```

Comment: @a.c_hairy_limon please mark the answer as correct by selecting the green checker on the left.